# "Undefined variable from import" in Contrib in TensorFlow 1.8

Tags: python, tensorflow, pydev

Running TensorFlow 1.8 in Eclipse with PyDev, and Eclispe is showing "Undefined variable from import: layers" on the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
```

It doesn't seem to be specifically limited to `layers`, but it is specific to `contrib`. The only things I've seen successfully fill in the `tf.contrib._____` blank are `stat_summarizer`, `__dict__`, `__file__`, `__name__`, and `__path__`

I previously had a similar issue caused by some code having been moved from `tf.contrib` a few versions back to `tf.nn`, but best I can tell from [the 1.8 documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/xavier_initializer) a lot of things (including`layers.xavier_initializer()`) are still in `contrib`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with: `from tensorflow.contrib import layers` inspired by this issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18592

Comment: Probably adding `tensorflow` to the forced builtins could solve that too. See: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html#PyDevInterpreterConfiguration-ForcedBuiltins for details.